# jquery script not changing div's class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my single page site, I have a script that is called to add a "read more" style link to a content area's div.
When the button is clicked, it should change the class of the content area to allow view of all of the content.
When clicked again, it should hide the content.

This is the site I'm having trouble on:  http://lexisnexis.stacklaw.com.au/
But, it is working OK on this site:  http://nundoobah-retreat.com.au/about.html

What have I got wrong?

Comment: Please post the relavant HTML and JQuery code that you are having issues with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JQuery is throwing a script error -- "can't find .curCSS" when your script runs the `switchClass` method.

I'm not sure, but this may be due to the fact that you're running an older version of JQuery UI than the JQuery core:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/templates/microsites//js//jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>     
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.13/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

The `curCSS` method was deprecated in JQuery 1.8.0.

I'd suggest upgrading to the latest version [JQueryUI](http://jqueryui.com/).  Alternatively, don't use `switchClass` (which belongs to JQuery UI), but instead use `removeClass` / `addClass`, or `slideUp` / `slideDown` (part of the core JQuery library).

Comment: downloading the newer jqueryui and linking to that worked!
Take a look now...
Is there a way I can make each h3 heading perform the same the same div's [+]/[-]???

Comment: This is probably a CSS thing and may be a different ticket altogether but why to the [+]/[-] appear in a different location in IE9 to FF and Chrome?
And why do the "fixed" sidebar boxes appear over on the left in Chrome only?

Answer (score 1):

Here is curcss issue with jquery-ui. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/11921

You might use jquery-ui later 1.9.0.